# jQuery .change() isn't firing as expected for a dropdown list, and I can't see why

Tags: jquery, forms

I am having some trouble spotting why my jQuery function isn't working as expected. The goal is to send an ajax call to the server when a dropdown changes, which will update the fields in the next half of the form:
[image: Example of the form]

With the extraneous functions removed, my jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Re-Load the form when a new game type is selected
    $("#meta_game_type_dropdown").change(function(){
        alert('woop');
        $.post('http://client2.dev/index.php/match/create_match_form',
        {
            game_type: $('#meta_game_type_dropdown').val(),
        },
        function(data, status){
            $('#match_form').html(data);
            $('.numeric_only').forceNumeric();
            //Set the default time to the current time
            $('#meta_time_input').setNow();
        });
    });
});
```

However, I'm not even getting the woop alert when I change the dropdown.
I have confirmed that the id is correct:

```
<select name="game_type" id="meta_game_type_dropdown">
```

So I'm stumped now. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can you please fiddle your code?is this dropDown static or being generated dynamically?

Comment: you are generating `meta_game_type_dropdown` dynamically i.e with jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, it's being done dynamically. The ajax call sends out a request for the new html, including the new form. This is probably a problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Event delegation to attach event.  [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Re-Load the form when a new game type is selected
  $(document).on('change',"#meta_game_type_dropdown",function(){
    alert('woop');
    $.post('http://client2.dev/index.php/match/create_match_form',
    {
        game_type: $('#meta_game_type_dropdown').val(),
    },
    function(data, status){
        $('#match_form').html(data);
        $('.numeric_only').forceNumeric();
        //Set the default time to the current time
        $('#meta_time_input').setNow();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked for me, thank you for the link to event delegation as well. Seems like a topic worth knowing about.